# Translate “修路致富” into English

Tags: simplified-characters

How to translate the title “修路致富” into English? I want to use it as the title of my paper.

Comment: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic **Please show your attempt at translation in your question and state which area you are having difficulty with.** Without *homework* this question is very quickly going to be closed. If you want to get an answer and keep it open show what you've done to try and translate it first yourself.

Comment: 要**想富** (or 要**致富**), 先**修路**: to (let peoples) **be rich**, **construct the roads** first. 修路致富: construct the roads to (let peoples) be rich.

Answer (score 0):

**"Wealth Follows The Extension of Motorways"** is an expression that's been attributed as a *"Chinese saying"*.

I first heard it on this video

[China’s Super Highway: MEGAPROJECTS (Part 6)](https://youtu.be/HTrg9fTJvmA?t=2m30s) by The Daily Conversation.

Starting at around ~2:30 the narrator says:

> It seems the whole country's embracing the Chinese saying *lu tong cai tong* - Wealth Follows The Extension of Motorways.

Almost the exact same quote can be found in [this](http://iiiprojects.blogspot.com/2015/04/national-trunk-highway-system-china.html) blogspot post:

> It seems the whole country is embracing the Chinese saying, “Lutong Caiton,” wealth follows the extension of motorways.

It all seems to be based of the saying **路通财通**. Which with the current announcements and actual extensions & building of highways and superhighways certainly fits your 修路致富.

It doesn't seem to be a well known *phrase* yet in English, but the Daily Conversation has almost racked up 1.5 million views on their youtube video, so it might very well become a "Chinese saying" in English.